# Как выявить присутствие одного изображения в другом?

Tags: c#, .net

Например, у меня есть изображение и есть второе изображение меньшего размера. Мне нужно определить присутствует ли второе изображение в первом? Как это сделать в C# малой кровью?

Comment: сравнивать попиксельно?

Comment: хотелось бы готовый пример метода, где на вход принимается 2 параметра типа Bitmap, а не выходе bool.

Comment: одно изображение наложено на другое, или встроено методом стеганографии?

Comment: у меня есть просто два изображения. одно изображение основное, а другое, которое следует искать в основном

Comment: Перебором? Запускаете пару вложенных циклов (x0, y0) по большему изображению, а в них еще пара циклов по меньшему (x1, y1) и сравниваете точки (x1, y1) меньшего и (x0 + x1, y0 + y1) большего, если не совпадают, то вложенную пару циклов можно прервать и перейти к следующей итерации внешней пары, если совпадают - проверяете следующие точки. Если внутренние пара циклов отработали до конца - значит совпадение найдено. Этот алгоритм, конечно, сработает, если нужно найти абсолютно идентичные части изображения и масштаб обоих изображений одинаков. ...

Comment: Если изображения могут иметь разный масштаб, то придется сравнивать точки с учетом этого масштаба. Если изображения могут отличаться незначительно (например, потери при сжатии), то можно не просто сравнивать абсолютное совпадение, а вычислять и накапливать некую ошибку (разницу между пикселями) и отбраковывать только при достижении ошибкой некоторого значения.